# How to override easy digital download css file in child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, overriding, easy-digital-downloads

I have to change some lines in this css file:

> /wp-content/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/templates/edd.min.css

```css
table#edd_purchase_receipt td, table#edd_purchase_receipt th, table#edd_purchase_receipt_products td, table#edd_purchase_receipt_products th {
    text-align: left;  /*must change to: text-align: right; */
}
```

I added below code in Style.css file, but nothing happened:

```css
   body table#edd_purchase_receipt td, table#edd_purchase_receipt th, table#edd_purchase_receipt_products td, table#edd_purchase_receipt_products th {
    text-align: left;  /*change to text-align: right; */
}
```

How can I override "edd.min.css" file in my child theme?
Actually, I have problem with overriding Wordpress plugins' css files in child theme. Is there a rule for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that style.css is getting called after edd.min.css.